# A problem about the intersection of convex open sets in $\Bbb R^m$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X\subset \Bbb R^m$ be the union of convex open sets $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ such that $X_i\cap X_j\cap X_k\neq\varnothing$ for all $i, j, k$.

Is $\bigcap\limits_{r=1}^nX_r\neq\varnothing$ true?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Is this homework? Please post your attempts at solving this problem, as well as some context (where does this come from?): this will increase the chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: Note necessarily, if $m\ge 3$; see [Helly’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem).